# How should I link load flags to their data in typescript

Tags: typescript, undefined, flags

I have a `started` flag, and then other data about the progress of some action.

```
let started: boolean = false;
let foo: number|undefined = undefined;
let bar: string|undefined = undefined;
```

Any other data is `undefined` until the action starts.
If I have a function that mutates this state, then typescript warns me that `foo` may be `undefined`, as I haven't explicitly linked it to `started`.

```
function mutate() {
  if (!started) return;
  foo++;
  bar = "qaax";
}
```

Is there a way to tell typescript that `foo` and `bar` are only undefined when `started` is `false`, and if not then what is the best way to handle sitautions like this where the existence of data is dependent on the value of some other data?

**Potential solutions**:

- I could use -1 instead of undefined, but that is less readable and sometimes -1 will be used by the data.
- Alternatively I could check individually that `foo` and `bar` are not undefined, but this becomes extemely ineficient with more complex data.
- Since whether the action has started is tracked seperately, I could leave `foo` and `bar` with any values as once the action starts then their values will be reset to meaningful ones. However again this would be much less readable.

Comment: Use `?` operator to check if foo is undefined before incrementing it. 

`foo?.++;`

Comment: Thank you I will start using this, but if possible I would really like the typechecker to enforce that if `started` is `true` then `foo` is not `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typechecker cannot infer from  the runtime state that whether a variable is undefined or not.
In your case use the non null assertion operator "!" to assert that "foo" will never be undefined when "started = true". This will lead to runtime error when "foo" is undefined.

`foo!++;`

The optional chaining operator "?" is introduced to optionally check whether a property is in an object or not to reduce the boilerplate code as described here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining.
This is just a shorthand for manually checking whether "foo.some" is undefined or not.
This will  not cause  runtime errors.

Comment: I'm getting an error `foo?++;` unexpected semicolon, am I using it wrong?
In vscode it says "expression expected"

Comment: Have updated the answer. Optional chaining can't be used assert if a variable is not undefined. In that case in order to avoid boilerplate you have to go with "!"